# jsforce: retrieve metadata of a report with a row-level formula

Tags: reporting, metadata-api, jsforce

When I use sfdx to pull a report, I see custom row formula fields under customDetailFormulas, but when I pull the same report using jsforce, customDetailFormulas are missing and the row summary formulas just don't appear at all.

To reproduce

1. Create report
2. Create row formula field
3. Use jsforce v1.9.3 `connection.metadata.readSync` to read report

Any suggestions why this might be and how to fix it?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bug in `jsforce`. You can work around it by using Analytics API and specifying the latest API version (v52.0 as of this writing):

```js
var jsforce = require("jsforce");
var conn = new jsforce.Connection({
  loginUrl: "https://login.salesforce.com",
  version: "52.0",
});
conn.login("...", "...", function (err, userInfo) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }

  var reportId = "00O...";
  conn.analytics.report(reportId).describe(function (err, meta) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log(meta.reportMetadata);
    console.log(meta.reportTypeMetadata);
    console.log(meta.reportExtendedMetadata);
  });
});
```

Testing this with a report that contains a row-level formula, the response metadata shows the formula:

```js
 customDetailFormula: {
    CDF1: {
      dataType: 'string',
      decimalPlaces: ...,
      description: null,
      formula: '...',
      formulaType: 'text',
      label: '...'
    }
  },
```

The API version matters. As of this writing `jsforce` uses v42.0 by default if you don't explicitly specify a version when creating a Connection object. This is too early for Analytics API vis-a-vis `customDetailFormula`: the latter doesn't show up in the response with v42.

Trying v52.0 with jsforce + Metadata API via `metadata.readSync` and valid report name, nothing is returned. The same test case works when calling Metadata API directly via SOAP and v52. Thus, this is a `jsforce` bug.

Comment: This is very close but not quite what I'm looking for as far as I can tell.  This is `customDetailFormula` not `customDetailFormulas` and is in a different format, eg `calculatedFormula` instead of `formula`

Comment: It's the same info but presented in a slightly different way. In Metatada API, `CustomDetailFormulas` is a type and the field is `reportCustomDetailFormula` (see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_report.htm#CustomDetailFormulas)). In Analytics API, the field is `customDetailFormula`, type is `Custom Detail Formula`. There's a 1:1 correspondence between two representations. If you really wanted to make it look like Metadata API, your custom JS function can grab Analytics response and return an object that looks like Metadata API response.